# Validation Settings Question

Tags: 2010

I am attempting to validate a column based on the contents of another column. 
In this case I have [Incremental Spend] and [Incremental Spending Reason]. If [Incremental Spend] is greater than $1, I would like [Incremental Spending Reason] a requirement.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint 2010 or above then you have list level validation in the list settings.  Here you can create a formula which refers to multiple columns.

There is an example of the sort of thing you want to achieve on Gary Bushey's blog [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/shareblog/archive/2012/02/28/conditional-requiring-of-fields-using-sharepoint-2010-list-validation.aspx)